# Setting textLabel.text for UITableviewCell from parsed xml file?

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, uitableview

I have a list that is made from parsed xml. I need to set the text of each list item to a title that is from the xml.

Below is the code

```
theList = [app.listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = theList.name;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

The list shows up blank. There is no text.

we know that the xml parser is working because if we click on a list item it will bring you to another screen we have created and it will show all of the info taken from the xml file.

We have tried setting the text to a default string and that works fine.

We have also tried this

```
self.title=theList.name
```

and the last item in the list will be set as the menu title.

Here is a link to the project, as you can you see if you run it the parser works but cells textLabel is not populated.

The link to the project is: https://github.com/iElmo/XML

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you put an NSLog just prior to setting the cell.textLabel.text? Also NSLog the cell. Or use the Xcode debugger.

Comment: Have done both of those things, could download the file and see the problem?

Comment: I downloaded the project, ran it and it works. But beer? Where are the Margaritas & Mojitos?

Comment: @RobertSaunders When I logged them, it looks like there were a newline characters at many of the strings. Did you see that?

Comment: @Rob No didn't see that, thanks soo much for the help, it was troubling me for some time, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a slight bug in your parser where you're grabbing data other than that between the start and ending tags. Thus, your string values have new line characters at the start of them. You can fix this by trimming the white space, or better, fix the parser:

```
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Prices"]) {

        app.listArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Price" ] ){

        theList = [[List alloc] init];

        theList.drinkID = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];

    }
    else {
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

    [currentElementValue appendString:string];
}
```

The previous parser was initializing `currentElementValue` anytime when `foundCharacters` was called, but you really only care about found characters between `didStartElement` and `didEndElement`. Moving the instantiation of `currentElementValue` to `didStartElement` fixes this issue.